# GCloud authentication race conditions

Tags: gcloud, gsutil

I'm trying to avoid race conditions with gcloud / gsutil authentication on the same system but different CI/CD jobs on my Gitlab-Runner on a Mac Mini.

I have tried setting the auth manually with

```
RUN gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file="gitlab-runner.json"
RUN gcloud config set project $GCP_PROJECT_ID
```

for the Dockerfile (in which I'm performing a download operation from a Google Cloud Storage bucket).

I'm using a configuration in the bash script to run the docker command and in the same script for authenticating I'm using

```sh
gcloud config configurations activate $TARGET
```

Where I've previously done the above two commands to save them to the configuration.

The configurations are working fine if I start the CI/CD jobs one after the other has finished. But I want to trigger them for all clients at the same time, which causes race conditions with gcloud authentication and one of the jobs trying to download from the wrong project bucket.

How to avoid a race condition? I'm already authenticating before each gsutil command but still its causing the race condition. Do I need something like CloudBuild to separate the runtime environments?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cloud Build to get separate execution environments but this might be an overkill for your use case, as a Cloud Build worker uses an entire VM which might be just too heavy, linux containers / Docker can provide necessary isolation as well.

You should make sure that each container you run has a unique config file placed in the path expected by [`gcloud`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/CredentialTypesSupportingVariousUseCases#configuringusing-credentials-via-cloud-sdk-distribution-of-gsutil). The issue may come from improper volume mounting (all the containers share the same location from the host/OS), or maybe you should mount a directory containing their configuration file (unique for each bucket) on running an image, or perhaps you should run `gcloud config configurations activate` in a Dockerfile step (thus creating image variants for different buckets if it’s feasible).

Alternatively, and I think this solution might be easier, you can switch from Cloud SDK distribution to [standalone gsutil distribution](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/CredentialTypesSupportingVariousUseCases#configuringusing-credentials-via-standalone-gsutil-distribution). That way you  can provide a path to a [boto configuration file through an environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/boto-gsutil#example).
Such variables can be specified on running a Docker image.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I worked around it for now by ensuring no more than one simultaneous jobs that use gcloud can run at the same time in my CICD, but I will definitely check out your recommendations. I've used the activation command inside the Dockerfile but it didn't work as it was still using the same gcloud executable(?). I read about boto configs which I thought might be overkill but that seems like a valuable option now.

Comment: Did you try out my recommendations?

Comment: I didn't get any more time to work on the issue so I solved it for now using a workaround: I put `resource_group: cloudrun` to the jobs that I want to be executed sequentially. When I get to try it or someone else can confirm I will mark your answer as accepted. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure. That's great you solved it!